# How to pass arguments to a page class with web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

I have several classes in my program.
The main one called WebServer creates the web.py application itself, and calls to other classes for the webpages. Can I pass `self.var1` for example to the search class `__init__`? Because I thought of just creating a method in the `index` class like `set_var1` or something like that, then I don't know how to access the specific instance of this class the the web application creates.

The class:

```
import sys
import os
import web
from pages.search import search
from pages.index import index


class WebServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "test"

        self.urls = (
            '/', 'index',
            '/search', 'search'
        )

        self.app = web.application(self.urls, globals())
        self.app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = WebServer()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no. Specific instances of `search` and `index` are created by `web.py` in response to an incoming request. There are better / easier ways.

Also, putting this initialization in a WebServer class, while possible, isn't the common way of doing it with `web.py`. There's no need for the class to do this: it's a singleton and this file is essentially a startup / configuration file.

To have application-wide information available to your "response" classes (search, index, etc.), make that information either global, or hook it into `web.config`  which is a web.Storage(). For example:

```
app = web.application(urs, globals())
web.config.update({"var1" : "test"})
app.run()
```

Which is then available to you responses. For example:

```
class search(object):
    def GET(self):
        if web.config.var1 == 'test':
             return do_test_search()
        return do_regular_search()
```

Comment: No, you don't keep stuff like that in `web.ctx`. It is meant to store the data related to the request context. The better place to store that is `web.config`.